# First Row by Variable (Redshift)

Tags: sql

Rows interested in : 
 - date
 - city
 - delivery

How do I return a table of the first ever delivery in each city?

Answer (score 8):

I think it `redshift` supports `row_number`:

```
select *
from (
    select date, city, delivery, 
           row_number() over (partition by city order by date desc) rn
    from yourtable
) t
where rn = 1
```

- http://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_WF_ROW_NUMBER.html